# Convert 2 rows to fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, pivot

In SQL server (2016), I want to convert 2 rows into 1 row with fields of both rows.
I have this example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyTable') IS not NULL DROP TABLE #MyTable

CREATE TABLE #MyTable (
    Direction varchar(1),
    DateKey int,
    ID varchar(8),
    [Sessions] int
    )

insert into #MyTable values('S', 20180301, 'ID123456', 46)
insert into #MyTable values('R', 20180301, 'ID123456', 99)

select * from #MyTable
```

Output:

```
Direction   DateKey     ID          Sessions
S           20180301    ID123456    46
R           20180301    ID123456    99
```

The output I want is:

```
DateKey     ID          S_Sessions  R_Sessions
20180301    ID123456    46          99
```

So I tried this query but it won't work:

```
select DateKey,ID,
    case Direction
    when 'S' then [Sessions] as S_Sessions -- Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

    else [Sessions] as R_Sessions
    end
from #MyTable
```

Maybe I have to create an extra table, insert rows where direction='S' and then update the records with data where direction='R' but I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` in SQL is an expression that returns a single value. It cannot be used to control execution flow like in procedural languages.

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
select DateKey, ID,
    max(case Direction when 'S' then [Sessions] end) as S_Sessions,
    max(case Direction when 'R' then [Sessions] end) as R_Sessions       
from #MyTable
group by DateKey, ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/LRE25831)

Answer (score 3):

use `PIVOT`

```
select  *
from    #MyTable
        pivot
        (
            max(Sessions)
            for Direction in ([S], [R])
        ) p
```

Comment: That will give me 2 columns `S` and `R` where it should be `S_Sessions` and `R_Sessions`. In the example I used only `Sessions`, but I have several others to split in `S_` and `R_`

Answer (score 1):

assuming that your table contains the "pairs" S and R you can also use a self join

```
SELECT s.DateKey , s.ID , s.Sessions S_Sessions , r.Sessions R_Sessions
FROM #MyTable S
JOIN #MyTable R
ON s.ID = r.ID
AND s.DateKey = r.DateKey
WHERE S.Direction = 'S'
AND r.Direction = 'R'
```

Comment: Good solution, but unfortunately that assumption is not true

Answer (score 0):

Try It ... It works for me . more variable more case and more left join table.

```
select a.DateKey,a.ID,
    (case a.Direction
    when 'S' then a.Sessions 
    end) as S_Sessions,
    (case b.Direction
    when 'R' then b.Sessions 
    end) as R_Sessions
from mytable as a CROSS JOIN mytable as b ON a.ID=b.ID LIMIT 2,1
```